# Фильтры в ocStore 2.1.0.2

Tags: opencart

Суть проблемы: создаю фильтры в админке, добавляю фильтры к категории и к товаром лишь нужные фильтры. В каталоге выбираю один из фильтров, выводит правильный результат, а как только добавляю второй фильтр, то сразу выводятся товары, которые соответствуют хотя бы одному из критериев. В чем может быть проблема?
Вот ссылка на [ресурс](http://redmedia.by/index.php?route=product/category&path=59_66_72)

Answer (score 1):

Такова логика работы встроенного в OC фильтра. Это было и в первой версии и в двойке осталось. Бесплатный фикс [здесь](https://opencartforum.com/files/file/2642-fixfilter-oc2x-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0-%D0%B2-opencart-20/) можно взять, или самому логику править.